# TypeScript: Reference declared type in interface creation

Tags: typescript

I am relatively new to using interfaces in Typescript. Is it possible to create a function and define it inside the interface like this?

This is whats currently in my `global.d.ts` file

I would like to define the function in the interface, for the use a assigning to a writable store in the svelte framework.

Edit: The `this.` calls were previously from a class, those are what I want to reference the above properties in the interface.

```js
type Sorting = { col: string, ascending: boolean };
type Paginate = (items: Results) => Promise<any>;
type SetPage = (page: number) => Promise<any>;
type Sort = (column: string, data:Results, callback:CallableFunction) => Promise<any>;

interface IPagination
    {
        page: number = 0;
        totalPages: [] = [];
        currentRow: [] = [];
        itemsPerPage: number = 5;
        sortBy: Sorting = { col: "customername", ascending: true };
        Paginate: Paginate = ((items:Results) => 
        {
            const pages = Math.ceil(items.length /  this.itemsPerPage);

            const paginatedItems = Array.from({ length: pages }, (_, index) => 
            {
                const start = index *  this.itemsPerPage;
                return items.slice(start, start +  this.itemsPerPage);
            });
            this.totalPages = [...paginatedItems];
            this.TotalPages = this.totalPages;
            return this.totalPages;
        });
        SetPage: Set; 
        Sort: Sort; 
    }
```

Comment: No, but if you have your class you can generate declarations from it and use those.  Could you make this code a [mre] that demonstrates your situation when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE?  Maybe by giving an example of the class you're sourcing it from (pared down to the minimal amount of code necessary to give the gist of what you're doing)?  Right now I wouldn't know where to begin because none of that compiles enough to get started.

Comment: Also, I'm wondering what you intend to do with such an interface?  An interface is just part of the static type system that gets erased when TS is compiled to JS, so it can't actually have function implementations inside it.  If you need types and not implementations, we can work on that.  But if you need both, then you really want a `class` which survives the compile step.

Comment: @jcalz Sure it has been removed. And okay that makes sense. I am new to using interfaces with typescript. I started learning typescript about 3 months ago, so this is newer to me. 

Here is a stackblitz link with the `global.d.ts` and the `pagination.ts` class I already created. If a class is a better option, how would make something adhere to it as a type then?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-4ayy9e?file=global.d.ts

Comment: Hmm, [there are errors in there](https://tsplay.dev/W4nzeN) so I'm not sure what to do with them... you're not asking about those errors, right?  That's one reason I suggested paring the code down to the minimum amount necessary to ask the question.  So we don't get distracted by whether `number` is assignable to `Results` or what.

Comment: Interesting... why is my vscode not giving me those errors... Well first it looks like i need to figure out why I am not seeing these errors

Comment: Hmm even tsc says I have no errors. Could it be the way I have my tsconfig?

Comment: Maybe? Those errors were in your stackblitz and the ts playground so they're definitely there.  Don't know how to help with vscode, especially remotely.  ‍♂️

Comment: Its all good, I will figure it out and look into using  classes instead of Interfaces. Thank you!